# What to do with a site that has multiple languages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a site that has four "streams" for language and each language has different content based on that language and location (US English, Spanish, Canadian English and Canadian French).
I'm wondering if I have to set up accounts for each stream so that we can see the stats from each stream only, or do I use one account and somehow tell GA to separate the different streams based on language.
For example, the US English site starts at (/en/) while the Canadian English site starts at (/ca_en/), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use five profiles, one is general for all the site and gives you the overall statistics, the others four are filters.

They show only the content in the filtered language (/en, /ca_en, ...)

[Google Analytics Profiles](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/topic.py?topic=11099)

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm glad that I won't have to create a bunch of accounts. I didn't think I would, but I thought I should ask first.